# Word Processor - Specifications

Tags: c#, .net, specifications

Are there any formal specifications that must be adhered to when writing a Word Processor (such as Microsoft Word)? Google has not yet revealed any answers.

Answer (score 3):

There can't be a specification because there isn't any interoperability requirement. You can only set a minimum number of features that a word processor (lower case) must have. By the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_processor) definition

> A word processor is an electronic device or a computer application software that, as directed by the user, performs word processing: the composition, editing, formatting and sometimes printing of any sort of written material.

I would say that a [System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) is more than enough to make a poor's man word processor.

I'll even say that some interactivity is necessary. TeX isn't a word-processor, it's a language to describe formatted documents (in a similar/different way of .doc, .pdf ...)

I'll say that technically a word processor doesn't need to be as you see them today: point-and-click, cursor-enabled, with big buttons to format, with formatting codes invisible: *vi* (a line based text editor) plus some macros to launch TeX would make a barely minimal word processor by the definition of the Wiki (probably something everyone would hate :-) ).

*vi* or any other text (*notepad*, *notepadplusplus*...) *alone* aren't Word Processors because they can't format the document (or at least they can't format + print as formatted, or format + export as formatted).

Comment: Thank you very much @xanatos, I appreciate your help. I will now breathe a sigh of relief. Coding time!!!

Comment: What I think I need to ask next would be about Printing. If I'm writing my own format, how do I make the Printer print using my format _or_ how to I convert my format into a Printer-understandable format that results in the same output-format as my own?

Comment: @Aeron This will print something (untested): `private PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

string textToPrint = ".NET Printing is easy";
Font printFont = new Font("Courier New", 12);
e.Graphics.DrawString(textToPrint, printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);` You'll have to compose various `DrawString`s, calculate the size of the text etc

Comment: @Aeron I'll add that making a control able to show formatted text is quite complex (complex+++++ I'l say). Even using a RichTextBox control is complex++. Printing starts from complex (simply printing a WPF RichTextBox) and goes up to complex++++ (printing manually through the `e.Graphics.DrawString`, calculating manually the size of everything, hypenation, justification, the subtleties of Left-to-Right and Right-To-Left, Unicode Composing Marks... Note that all of these are necessary even to show your document :-) ). There is a good reason there are so few complete word processors around :-)

Comment: I'll be blunt. I won't **ever** embark in the project of writing a full word processor, because I know that even if I can use RichTextBox today, tomorrow it won't be enough because I (my boss, my friend, someone) will want to add a "simple feature" that seems very easy to implement... Sadly it goes against the RTB inners.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand that I may fail in trying to write my own Word Processor, but what I fear the most is if I finish it - nothing will come of it since practically everyone uses MS Office. It's hard to take people away from their favorites when nobody else they know is already using it yet. Like Bing, or Cuil search engines (for example).

Comment: You gave the correct examples... I'll keep my Word to your Wordpad, like I kept my google to your Bing and your Cuil (and I tried Cuil for a week, and I have a Windows Phone that uses only Bing as a search engine) :-) :-)